# Analogues of the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorems in Topology

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

We know that the first fundamental isomorphism theorem for groups has somewhat of a "natural" analog in topology, specifically the one that deals with the quotient space being homeomorphic to the image of identification maps.

This might be a bit general or vague but I was wondering if there are analogs of the 2nd and 3rd isomorphism theorems in some branch of algebraic topology. I think this also will cross into category theory but just the same, I don't know exactly where to start looking for such analogs.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186035/image-kernel-quotient-and-first-isomorphism-theorem-in-a-category-of-monoid-o

Answer (score 8):

The first isomorphism theorem is false for topological spaces, in the following sense.

In many categories arbitrary morphisms $f : x \to y$ have what's called a (regular) **[image-coimage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image#comparison_of_regular_images_and_coimages)** factorization

$$x \to \text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f) \to y$$

where the first morphism is an epimorphism and the last morphism is a monomorphism. A very abstract statement of the first isomorphism theorem is that it means the middle arrow is always an isomorphism. In groups, $\text{im}(f)$ can more or less be identified with the set-theoretic image of a homomorphism in the usual sense, whereas $\text{coim}(f)$ is the quotient of $x$ by the kernel of $f$, and so we recover the usual first isomorphism theorem this way.

For topological spaces, if $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map, $\text{im}(f)$ is the set-theoretic image of $f$ topologized with the subspace topology from $Y$, and $\text{coim}(f)$ is the set-theoretic image of $f$ topologized with the quotient topology from $X$. These do not agree in general, although they do agree if $X$ and $Y$ are both compact Hausdorff.

Comment: thank you very much sir, for shedding light on the 1st isomorphism theorem in category theory. would there also be any sense in asking if there are similar concepts in category theory for the 2nd and 3rd theorems?